# How do I add a project as JAR as a dependency of another project? (Gradle)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle

I have had a generated Gradle project existing of the root project `Racer` and a few others (Racer-desktop, Racer-core...) Now I wanted to add one, namely `Racer-server`. This project should, just like the other ones, depend on the `Racer-core` project. What I've tried: add it to settings.gradle:

```
 include 'android', 'ios', 'html', 'core', 'desktop', 'server'
```

Added this stub to my Racer (root) build.gradle :

```
project(":server") { 
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies { 

     compile project(":core")    
}
```

and my `Racer-server`'s build.gradle contains this (mostly inspired by the files in the existing projects):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
sourceSets.main.compileClasspath +=     files(project(':core').sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
version = '1.0'

eclipse {
project {
    name = appName + "-server" //Racer-server
}}
```

Now when I run Gradle->Refresh All it seems to do (regarding adding the core project) is this:[image: eclipse project properties] It did add something, however "core" isn't even the name of the project, it's Racer-core on all the other projects.

What I want is that the core project gets compiled into a jar and added as a dependency to my server project, because the server i'm using (Google App Engine) requires a linked project to be as a jar.

Can this be done using Gradle?

Comment: First try to get the command line build to work, only then focus on Eclipse. The `sourceSets.main.compileClasspath +=` line is probably not what you want. That's already taken care of by `compile project(":core")` (only that the latter puts the *Jar file* on the compile class path, not the source files).

Comment: I've tried it with the gradlew.bat too, but I get the same result. Now I've found one thing: whenever I delete and import my project into eclipse, the error will disappear, and the correct project is linked! However as soon as I build with Gradle it gives me the same old problem, as stated above!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "same result"?

Comment: The same result as when I use eclipse's Gradle plugin to build the project. So basically the project compiling except that it adds the wrong project as a dependency (and as a result it can't be found).

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by that. Does the build succeed? If so, what is the *exact* problem? If not, what *exact* error message do you get? Is the project directory named `Racer-server` or `server`? What exactly do you mean when you say "the (command line) build adds the wrong project as a dependency"?

Answer (score 0):

I completely remade the project, keeping only the .java files I had. I started from scratch, carefully using the gradle wrapper, adjusting the build file till I had what I wanted, and still checking if everything kept working on both android and GAE.

I must say I don't know what the problem originally was, however I do know that sometimes the solution is to just start from (semi-)scratch. Also, trying to create a project that uses partially the same code for many platforms at the same time, is a very precise, error prone, attempt.